# is there a client side (javascript) graph library that doesn't require a server?

Tags: javascript, graph, client-side

I need to generate many internal client-side (within the company only) graphs from streams of data, and since the data itself is "secret", I can't use a service like Google-Graphs for generating the graphs. So I was wondering if anyone has some recomendations for a javascript graph library that doesn't require a server.

Thanks

Comment: If the data is "secret", how exactly do you get around the fact that it will be manipulated on the client's browser in plaintext Javascript?

Comment: Because only browsers within the "secret garden" will have access to the data and the graphs, the application won't be touching the greater internet, only the local intranet of the company

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at [flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) a javascript plotting library.

**EDIT**
The official flot repo [lives on github](https://github.com/flot/flot)

Comment: not as general purposely awesome as Raphael, but much easier/powerful at the Plotting part indeed

Comment: Shameless plug: github.com/thenduks/flot (I forked it because of slow developement, feel free to help! :))

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) ([github](https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/tree)).

Answer (score 1):

The data is likely going to be in plain text if you use a javascript library to render it client side... Even so, [jQuery Sparklines](http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/) can generate simple graphs client-side.

Answer (score 1):

Found a library called [PlotKit](http://www.liquidx.net/plotkit/) for Mochi, while looking at Nickf's canvasgraphjs link.

Comment: yeah, i just realised that they've stopped work on canvasgraphjs, so I deleted that answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a client-side library, your data is pretty much out in the open. If the data is secret, I think what you need is a library that generates the plot on the server side and outputs images.  JFreechart is one library that does this in Java. I am sure there are others.

Comment: The data is secret outside of the company, so I can't forward it to Google for example. However anyone within the intranet has privileges and rights to access the data in anyway they like. Because no one has access to the page outside of the company's intranet

Answer (score 0):

Check [D3.js](http://d3js.org/): JavaScript library for manipulating documents based on data.
I didn't try it myself yet, but it looks promising and interesting.