# Alternative to Google Visualization's Annotated Timeline? (graphing library)

Tags: charts, data-visualization, google-visualization, annotatedtimeline

Is there any alternative to Google's [Annotated Timeline](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotatedtimeline.html) Visualization API?

[image]

[There's some bugs in the Annotated Timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794636/google-visualization-annotated-time-line-removing-data-points), and it doesn't appear they will be addressed.

Also it is a **Flash** based chart. A Canvas+Javascript implementation would be more portable.

---

The qualities that make the **Annotated Timeline** valuable (as opposed to every other charting library i've found so far) are:

- supports multiple lines
- zooming; to drill in and out of a date range
- panning back and forth through time
- supports ***thousands*** of data points
- ability to be fed new data on the fly

As far as i can tell Google's Annotated Timeline is the only interactive line graph library.

Comment: also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109780/non-clunky-client-side-graphs  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437686/is-there-a-client-side-javascript-graph-library-that-doesnt-require-a-server?rq=1

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Dygraphs](http://dygraphs.com/) should do exactly what you want, and is a full js implementation. It's free, and already [integrates with gviz](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/more_charts.html)  ([sample here](http://dygraphs.com/tests/gviz.html)), so you should barely need to change anything. It also has a bunch of other useful functionality not found on other gviz charts (like rolling average calculation).

Hope that helps.

Comment: For what it's worth, dygraphs also has a range selector just like the one on the bottom of the Google Annotated Timeline. It's not on by default, but can be enabled easily. See http://dygraphs.com/tests/range-selector.html for an example.

Comment: this seems to work strangely on mobile... while it's nice to pinch to zoom, it is way to easy to accidentally zoom or scroll way out of bounds where nothing lives and then have fun trying to figure out how to get back to a useful place.

Answer (score 5):

I know this question is pretty old but it would save me a lot of time if I knew there was a new `ChartRangeFilter` api.

[image]

https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#chartrangefilter

Comment: I migrated an app from the google AnnotatedTimeLine to a ChartRangeFilter and am happy with it.

Comment: is it just me, or are the chart range controls inoperable on mobile?

Answer (score 4):

On [January 29, 2014](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes#v29012014) Google has made available a new version of such a chart called [`Annotation Chart`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotationchart). It's pretty cool indeed! Best of all it's free to user wherever you want.

> Annotation charts are interactive time series line charts that support
>   annotations. Unlike the annotated timeline, which uses Flash,
>   annotation charts are SVG/VML and should be preferred whenever
>   possible.

Sample:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      google.load('visualization', '1.1', {'packages':['annotationchart']});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Kepler-22b mission');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Kepler title');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Kepler text');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Gliese 163 mission');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Gliese title');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Gliese text');
        data.addRows([
          [new Date(2314, 2, 15), 12400, undefined, undefined,
                                  10645, undefined, undefined],
          [new Date(2314, 2, 16), 24045, 'Lalibertines', 'First encounter',
                                  12374, undefined, undefined],
          [new Date(2314, 2, 17), 35022, 'Lalibertines', 'They are very tall',
                                  15766, 'Gallantors', 'First Encounter'],
          [new Date(2314, 2, 18), 12284, 'Lalibertines', 'Attack on our crew!',
                                  34334, 'Gallantors', 'Statement of shared principles'],
          [new Date(2314, 2, 19), 8476, 'Lalibertines', 'Heavy casualties',
                                  66467, 'Gallantors', 'Mysteries revealed'],
          [new Date(2314, 2, 20), 0, 'Lalibertines', 'All crew lost',
                                  79463, 'Gallantors', 'Omniscience achieved']
        ]);

        var chart = new google.visualization.AnnotationChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        var options = {
          displayAnnotations: true,
        };

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id='chart_div' style='width: 900px; height: 500px;'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for coming back to add this answer, I've been hoping for this alternative to be released!

Comment: Compared to the other Google Charts I have been using, this one seems to be a big steaming pile of issues...

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this:

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-master-detail

It's not free but it looks interesting.

Answer (score 2):

This thread is little old, but SIMILE widgets by MIT are great. They have one for timeline as well.
[SIMILE Timeline Widget](http://www.simile-widgets.org/timeline/)

Answer (score 2):

There is a new project in the yard (yep, I'm one of developers there), which might be the perfect fit for your needs:

[Data Visualization Software Lab](http://datavisualizationsoftwarelab.com)

That library is purely HTML5 based and very interactive - try the demo. It's also Mobile optimised, so you can use it on any device.

Library is in beta and active development at the moment. Many more features to come soon. Any feedback would be highly recommended. There is also extensive documentation and examples of usage. API for external control is present as well.

Dual licensing to be provided.

Snapshot:

[image: TimeChart example]

Answer (score 1):

After extensive research to replace Google Annotated Timeline, I think that [HighChart StockChart](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/) is the most comprehensive. 
As mentioned above, it is not open source nor free, but affordable according to me.

Answer (score 1):

Try [NVD3.js](http://nvd3.org/ghpages/lineWithFocus.html) if you don't need the annotation but only the viewfinder feature.

Answer (score 0):

Try [c3js](http://c3js.org/)
.Its completely free, light and easy to use.